# Filenet Solution Deployment Take too much time

Tags: deployment, filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-case-manager

Deployment a solution with IBM Case Manager Builder take too mach time on deployment , When i look "Detail Deployment Log" file I can see following steps take too mach time.

```
11/5/18 8:55:55 PM GMT+05:30  FNRPA0120I The solution X001 pages are being deployed.
11/5/18 9:08:24 PM GMT+05:30  FNRPA0292I The following choice list is being deployed: X001_Category to.
```

and

```
11/5/18 9:14:22 PM GMT+05:30  FNRPA0116I The latest version of the Process Engine configuration document with a version series ID of {XXX-0000-C9B2-81BD-YYY} is being deployed.
11/5/18 9:22:46 PM GMT+05:30  FNRPA0118I The Process Engine XPDL document with an ID of {ZZZ-0100-C854-A789-HHH} is being deployed.
```

[image]

I feel like its because of too much versions , without copying solution with new solution ID what can I do ?Any best practices i can use to avoid this ?

Comment: Any more information in the pe logs? The xpdl refers to workflow deployoments... Also note that deployments have sped-up in the newer releases due to incremental approaches..  Additionally, while it might not be your problem, i've found a huge log-folder to greatly impact my deploys.(+10 minute for single deply)  My log files were in the  <WASProfile>\ICM  folder.

Comment: @IvoJonker , After Removing logs (near 6 GB) It was few mins faster for next few deployments , I notice that 2 part of the delay (FNRPA0116I ) was low with this log removal or maybe its just because I restart WebSphere when i am removing logs.Do FNRPA0116I  have a dependency with log file size ? I have IBM Case Manager - 5.2.1 (icmproduct 5.2.1.004.622) .

Comment: Then you might consider upgrading to 5.3.1+ bringing you the benefits of the incremental deploy - see 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCTJ4_5.3.1/com.ibm.casemgmt.installing.doc/acmov008.htm). 
As for the FNRPA0116I - i have no clue why it would be dependent on log files. Perhaps there's something wrong with the log-file-rotation mechanism.

Comment: @Archangle have you tried removing the previous versions of the workflow. this helped us with FileNet BPM deployments using the deployment manager, hence I believe it would be the same thing with the case manager deployment (even through it is done through the builder)